# How to display data obtained from a database from a table to a form in PHP

Tags: php

I have brought data from the DB to a table, I am trying to pass the ID of to a URL to be able to modify the data in another page, but when printing the data in the input it says that the variable is not defined. I am doing it with views model. I just put two data from the data edit form for simplicity.

[image]

Table

```
<table id="tablae" class="table table-striped table-centre table-bordered table-condensed" style="width:100%" >
                    <thead class="text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Incidencia</th>
                            <th>Usuario</th>                                
                              
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            
                            <th>Fecha de apertura</th>
                            
                            <th>Departamento</th>
                            
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php foreach(get_editar_incidencias($conexion) as $dato):?>
                    <tbody>     
                    <tr>
                    <td ><?php echo $dato['id']?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo $dato['incidencia']?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo $dato['usuario']?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo $dato['estado']?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo $dato['fecha_inicio']?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo $dato['nom_dep']?></td>
                     <td ><button><a href="editar_incidencia.php?id=<?php echo $dato['id']?>">Ver</a></button></td>
     
                    </tr>
      
                    </tbody>  
                    <?php endforeach ?>      
                </table>
```

editar_incidencia.php

```
<?php session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['identificador'])){
        require 'frontend/editar_incidencia-vista.php';
    }else{
        header ('location: login.php');
    }
    $id= $_GET['id'];

    $sql_traer_incidencia = "SELECT incidencia.id,incidencia.incidencia,incidencia.usuario,incidencia.nom_dep,incidencia.fecha_inicio,incidencia.estado,incidencia.categoria,incidencia.usuario_resuel,incidencia.fecha_fin, usuarios.usuario, 
    departamento.nom_dep,estado.estado,categoria.categoria,cliente.cliente,problematica.problematica,entorno.entorno,comentario.comentario, comentario.fecha_comentario,comentario.id_usuario 
    FROM incidencia LEFT JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = incidencia.usuario LEFT JOIN usuarios AS usuarios_resuletos ON usuarios_resuletos.id =incidencia.usuario_resuel INNER JOIN departamento ON departamento.cod = incidencia.nom_dep 
    INNER JOIN estado ON estado.id = incidencia.estado INNER JOIN categoria ON categoria.id=incidencia.categoria INNER JOIN cliente ON cliente.id = incidencia.cliente INNER JOIN problematica ON problematica.id = incidencia.problematica
    INNER JOIN entorno ON entorno.id = incidencia.entorno LEFT JOIN comentario ON comentario.id_incidencia = incidencia.id LEFT JOIN comentario AS comentario_usuario ON comentario_usuario.id = incidencia.usuario WHERE incidencia.id='$id'";
    $resultado_edit_inci =$gsnet = $conexion->prepare($sql_traer_incidencia);
    
    $resultado_edit_inci = $gsnet->execute();
    
    $resultado_edit_inci = $gsnet->fetchAll()
  
?>
```

editar_incidencia-vista.php

```
    <form id="formUsuarios">    
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="" class="col-form-label">Incidencia</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incidencia" value="<?php echo $resultado_edit_inci['incidencia']?>" readonly>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="" class="col-form-label">Usuario solicitante</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" id="usuario"  value="<?php echo $resultado_edit_inci['usuario'];?>" readonly >
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $resultado_edit_inci['id'];?>" >
                        </div> 
                        </div>    
                    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have `require 'frontend/editar_incidencia-vista.php';` before you set the variable `$resultado_edit_inci`. Also, that variable contains an array of all the rows of results, you need to index it or loop over it.

Comment: You should also use `$gsnet->bindParam()` rather than substituting `$id` into the SQL, to prevent SQL injection.